# How to validate custom file input in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-extension

I used kartik's custom file input it is working fine for me except validation,this is reference site from where i taken this extension
https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput
Here is my code,

```
echo '<label class="control-label">Video</label>';
        echo FileInput::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'VideoURL',
            'options' => ['multiple' => false],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowedFileExtensions'=>['mp4'],
                'showPreview' => false,
                'showRemove' => false,
                'showUpload' => false,
                'minFileCount' => 1
            ],
    ]);
```

Now how can i validate it if file input is blank ? Can anyone please tell me what is solution for this ?

Comment: Are you looking for [skipOnEmpty](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#handling-empty-inputs)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AdHoc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ad-hoc-validation) method in Yii2, In your action try this:

```
/* @var $validator \yii\validators\FileValidator */
/* @var $file  yii\validators\FileValidator */

$validator = new FileValidator(['extensions' => ['png','jpg']]); //set allowed file types and other file extensions

$file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('avatar'); // it should be your input name attribute

if( $validator->validate($file, $errors) ) { // Validating here
          //validation success
} else {
          print_r($error);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just add validation in your model file likee

```
public function rules()
{
   return [           
       [['VideoURL'], 'required'],
   ];
}
```